# Jarring All files in a directory based on extension

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar, sh

I am trying to jar all the files in a folder with the jar command using Java as follows,

```
jar -cvf /Abhishek/logs.jar my_directory/logs/*.logs*
```

I am using Java to execute this.

```
String cmd[] = {"jar", "-cvf", "/Abhishek/logs.jar", "my_directory/logs/*.logs*"};
pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

but only the manifest is getting stored in the jar.

```
added manifest
```

When I extract the jar file, I am getting the manifest file.
So I had a doubt regarding

```
*log.*
```

Is this type of syntax allowed to be used?
Cause it worked fine in the terminal.

Could someone shed some light into this?

Thank you.

Comment: On which OS are you?

Comment: linux, I'm trying this out in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, file globbing is done by the shell. So when you enter `*.log` at the terminal, the shell will expand it to the list of matching files. Which is then passed to the program.

If you execute the program directly, you would have to expand the pattern yourself. Or you could let the shell execute it with a command similar to

```
String cmd[] = {"sh", "-c", "jar -cvf /Abhishek/logs.jar my_directory/logs/*.logs*"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just use the same classes in the [java.util.jar package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) that the jar command uses.  This will avoid a second Java process and will avoid relying on shell expansion:

```
try (JarOutputStream jar = new JarOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            Files.newOutputStream(
                Paths.get("/Abhishek/logs.jar"))));
    DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(
        Paths.get("my_directory/logs"), "*.logs*")) {

    for (Path file : dir) {
        BasicFileAttributes attr =
            Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

        String name = file.toString();
        if (attr.isDirectory()) {
            name = name + "/";
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setLastModifiedTime(attr.lastModifiedTime());
        entry.setLastAccessTime(attr.lastAccessTime());
        entry.setCreationTime(attr.creationTime());
        entry.setSize(attr.size());

        jar.putNextEntry(entry);
        Files.copy(file, jar);
    }
}
```